# Counting Multiple Choice Results

Tags: mysql

Using MYSQL, I have created a survey where users answer a series of questions (6 questions) about courses they took.  I have a COURSE table and SURVEY_ANSWERS table (among others that do not matter right now).  Each question is answered on a scale from 0-5, only whole integers, no decimals.

I am trying to find a way to total all the answers for each question by course number.

So far, I am able to see the totals for Question 1 (q1) using:

```
select a.fk_courseID, 
(select 
        count(a.q1)
    from
        survey_answers a
    where
        q1 = 0) as Q1_NR,
(select 
        count(a.q1)
    from
        survey_answers a
    where
        q1 = 1) as Q1_SD,
(select 
        count(a.q1)
    from
        survey_answers a
    where
        q1 = 2) as Q1_D,
(select 
        count(a.q1)
    from
        survey_answers a
    where
        q1 = 3) as Q1_NAD,
(select 
        count(a.q1)
    from
        survey_answers a
    where
        q1 = 4) as Q1_A,
(select 
        count(a.q1)
    from
        survey_answers a
    where
        q1 = 5) as Q1_SA from survey_answers a
   group by a.fk_courseID
```

Seems messy to me, like I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this    This outputs each different courseID (which I want), however it is not separating the results by course number, it shows the same number of 0s, 1s, 2s, etc for each course.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Once I figure out how to do this for one question Im sure I can figure out the next 5 on my own.  I've tried using different SELF JOINS and OUTER LEFT JOINS but to no avail, I'm sure Im missing something small.
I also tried this:

```
select a.fk_courseID, a.q1, a.count1, b.count2 from
(select fk_courseID, q1, count(*) as count1 from survey_answers group by   fk_courseID)     as a
left outer join (select fk_courseID, q1, count(*) as count2 from survey_answers where     q1=1) as b on b.fk_courseID=a.fk_courseID
```

The above outputs the number of answers of a '1' to Q1, but this time it lists each courseID, but puts the total number of 1s for q1 in the top column and NULLS in the rest, I'm looking for something like:

CourseID      Q1_1  Q1_2
67              3     4
1               2     3
3               5     2

Meaning for Course 67 there was 3 answers of 1 for Q1, 4 answers of 2 for Q1, etc. Course 1 had 2 answers of 1, 3 answers of 2, etc , etc
etc

If anyone has a suggestion please assist....

Answer (score 1):

You want conditional aggregation!

```
select a.fk_courseID, 
       sum(q1 = 0) as Q1_NR,
       sum(q1 = 1) as Q1_SD,
       sum(q1 = 2) as Q1_D,
       sum(q1 = 3) as Q1_NAD,
       sum(q1 = 4) as Q1_A,
       sum(q1 = 5) as Q1_SA
from survey_answers a
group by a.fk_courseID;
```

In MySQL, the result of a boolean is `1` for "true" and `0` for "false".  This is convenient.  You can easily count the number of matches by just summing the result.

EDIT:

You can check what you want by doing:

```
sum(0 in (q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6))
```

Comment: OMG THAT WAS SO EASY!!!   Thanks for the quick reply!!  So easy with the SUM functyion.  Should have tried that earlier.

Comment: Is there any simple way to count the number of times an answer of 1 is given for any of the six questions, like sum(q1 or q2 or q3 or q4 or q5 or q6 = 0)